# how do I check that a SqlDataSource returned data?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

I have an asp.net page that has several `SqlDataSources` defined that feed data into some graphs. The graph product does not handle "no data" gracefully, and throws an exception. I'd like this to handle the situation -- so I need to check whether the `SqlDataSource` returned data before rendering the graph (and if not, just post a message saying "No Data" or something).

Is there an easy way to check if the data source returned data, and do this if/then without a bunch of code behind?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following is taken from devcurry, which is pretty much what you are looking for.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName],
    [ContactTitle], [Address] FROM [Customers]"
    onselected="SqlDataSource1_Selected">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And in code behind:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selected(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)

    If e.AffectedRows < 1 Then

        ' perform action

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks JackM-- is it possible to do the if statement in the page, not in the code behind?

Comment: Keep in mind that AffectedRows also is 0 when no table is returned at all vs. just a table with zero rows.

Answer (score 3):

try this
http://www.devcurry.com/2009/02/how-do-you-check-if-sqldatasource.html

i hope if it helps you ..

Comment: thanks for the link AmRosh-- I don't really understand how I would use that however. Could you explain a bit more? Thank you